# VB.net need XNPV

Tags: vb.net

I can successfully determine NPV (net present value) by using NPV(Fixedrates, values).  However, I need to have the functionality of Excel's XNPV which will also takes in to account dates.

Any ideas?

Regards, 
Matt

Comment: this site is all programmers... we can crank out a bunch of code to do whatever you need, but personally, the acronym XNPV means nothing to me.  Can you explain a little more about what an XNPV procedure does so we can reproduce it in VB code?

Answer (score 0):

XNPV function is Excel calculates net present value of an annuity when cash flows are not necessarily periodic. NPV function in Excel calculates net present value of annuity that makes periodic end of period payments.

With NPV function, the first cash flow is discounted at time period 1 and subsequent cash flows are discounted at time period 2 to N where N is the number of cash flows

With XNPV function, the cash flows are discounted at their actual time period which is calculated by first finding the number of days between CFt and CF0. This difference would be Dt-D0 where Dt is the transaction date for cash flow t and D0 is the transaction date of cash flows 0. The difference is then divided by 365 to find time period t at which to discount the particular cash flow. The sum of the discounted cash flows is the net present value for these irregular cash flows.

Here is a sample [XNPV calculation](http://finance.thinkanddone.com/online-xnpv-calculation.html) using an online tool that finds [net present value](http://finance.thinkanddone.com/npv.html) for irregular cash flows.

```
Date           N                 Payment     PVIF @ 4%     Present Value
01/01/2008     0                -10,000.00    1.000000     -10,000.00
03/01/2008     0.164383561644    2,500.00     0.993573     2,483.93
10/30/2008     0.83002283105     2,500.00     0.967970     2,419.93
02/15/2009     1.12602739726     2,500.00     0.956797     2,391.99
04/01/2009     1.24920091324     2,500.00     0.952186     2,380.47
XNPV     -323.68
```

However XNPV function in Excel is limited to only finding net present value when interest is compounded discretely. In most finance and banking applications interest is compounded continuously and here Excel is no help in finding net present value. You can look at alternatives such as [TADXL Excel add-in for finance](http://thinkanddone.com/) that provides tadXNPV function to find net present value for irregular cash flows when interest is compounded either discretely or continuously.

Another drawback of Excel's NPV and XNPV function has to do with use of a single discount rate in its calculation. Yet in good number of real life situations, an annuity may be discounted at different interest rates for each of the cash flows as is the case with variable rate mortgages.

Here too, TADXL add-in for finance provides you with functions such as tadDRNPV and tadDRXNPV that permit discounting of cash flows using different rates